# Can I bypass organizational authentication for a WebAPI controller inside an MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC5, EF6 app which uses organizational authentication (Azure AD) and all is working fine except for one thing. There is a requirement for a WebAPI controller to process requests from unauthenticated clients. The clients are normally Android devices issuing AJAX requests.

Before I added organizational authentication to my MVC app, my WebAPI controller was being called and functioned correctly so I know my routing is correct. Now I've added organizational authentication, my WebAPI controller is no longer called and the client's AJAX request times out.

I understand there are attributes such as [Authorize] to specify access to controllers/methods but when using organizational authentication, it appears that WebAPI controllers without the [Authorize] attribute do not get called.

My question is, can I mark my WebAPI controller to allow requests from unauthenticated clients, if so how can I do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have any delegating handlers that take care of authorization in the web api application?

Comment: No I don't. I found the solution, its listed below but I can't mark it as the official answer yet, need to wait another 23 hours! The solution was to add a location entry into the web.config file. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to allow anonymous connections to a specific controller by entering the xml below into the root Web.config file.

If your controller is called "PersonController", then the name you should enter into the path attribute is "person" NOT "personcontroller".

In my case, because I want to allow anonymous requests to a WebAPI controller, I need to prefix my controller name in the path attribute with "api/".

Hope this helps others who may run into the same issue.

```
<location path="api/my-controller-name">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I add that, route should cover api folder and controller name should be placed without full file path. Reshaper would suggest you more...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow anonymous access you can use the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

You can either add this above the ApiController to mark the whole controller for anonymous acces like:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
}
```

Or you can give a specific method this attribute, to allow that method to be called anonymously:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string GetData() 
    {

    }
}
```

This will block access to all methods when a user is not authorized, except the `GetData()` method which can be called anonymously.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it does not work in an organizational authentication context. I think the problem occurs before the attributes take effect because if I paste the URL for the WebAPI method into a browser address bar, I get redirected to the Microsoft sign in page.