# How to bypass AzureAD authentication using OpenID and Owin middleware for Web API 2 controller within ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application which has WEB API2 project with few controllers within it. I have setup AzureAD authentication for the ASP.NET MVC5 project using AzureAD and OpenID connect and OWIN middleware.

Everything is working fine from ASP.NET MVC project point of view. The WEB API2 controller are used here to process the requests coming from angularjs, Android 
and iOS app. There is a requirement for a WebAPI controller to process requests from unauthenticated clients (angularjs, Android, iOS apps) which issue AJAX requests.

Prior to the AzureAD authentication setup it was configured with on premise ADFS authentication. In this case I followed the below link to by pass on premise ADFS authentication for the 
WEB API2 controllers and it worked fine for me.

[Can I bypass organizational authentication for a WebAPI controller inside an MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167194/can-i-bypass-organizational-authentication-for-a-webapi-controller-inside-an-mvc)

Can anyone help me to know how to bypass the azuread authentication for the WEB API2 controllers to allow requests from unauthenticated clients in this case with some code samples ?

Comment: Is your webAPI hosted in IIS? and if yes, did you check the authorization permission for your web site (If there are some, they would be taken into account before the call to your web api even happens, which would explain what you see)

Answer (score 0):

The web API controller is access-able for anonymous user by default. If you got the unauthenticated issue(`401`) when the anonymous user access that controller, please check whether there is `Authorize` attribute for the specific controller and remove that attribute.

Comment: I see that the calls to the web api are blocked. There is also no [Authorize] attribute for any of the web api 2 controllers.

Comment: Fei is right, but would your webAPI be hosted in IIS? and if yes, did you check the authorization permission for your web site (If there are some, they would be taken into account before the call to your web api even happens, which would explain what you see)

Comment: Yes the web api is hosted in IIS. There is a custom authorization which inherits the AuthorizeAttribute class in place for the asp.net mvc app. This custom authorization is injected in the FilterConfig class (filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizationAttribute());)

Comment: Is the OWIN pipeline creating problem here. For the Web api 2 project there are already CORS headers enabled. I need your help to resolve this issue. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I was more meaning in IIS itself, (that is before any code is reached into you application) wouldn't you have a the authentication for the Web site set to Windows authentication (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx) ? I believe it needs to be set to anonymous access in IIS, so that the OWIN pipeline has a chance to get the token

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro You were protecting the every action method of every controller through the [global filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). To enable anonymous  call we need to add the `AllowAnonymous` attribute the specific action or controller we wanted.