# How to Add Multi-Auth to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, openid

disclaimer--this is my first time using .NET Core after taking over a site from another team so still learning. I have a client app called 3d with a web API. I am trying to hit the API through Postman because I have a requirement to be able to make the call from an external application without user input but it fails due to a pop up asking the user to sign into Azure:
[image]

The call works successfully if I execute it through swagger locally (there's no auth on the calls themselves yet). The culprit seems to be in the startup file which redirects the user to the SSO page:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Path = Configuration["SiteConfiguration:BasePath"];
                options.Cookie.Domain = Configuration["SiteConfiguration:Domain"];
            })
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"),
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            "V3Cookie");
```

Is there a way to work around this and be able to hit the API through postman/code? Could I have a service account bypass it? Or is there a way to also do token auth?

Let me know if I can clarify anything, thanks

Comment: If it is an API, it usually shouldn't be configured with OpenID Connect authentication. It should be configured with Bearer token authentication, so the client applications can acquire tokens and the API validates them without requiring user interaction at that point. Then it would also work with Postman etc.

Comment: It seems like they built the site/controllers originally for only internal use, and have never had to have someone call the api from the outside so now the issues arise. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a comment on [How to bypass AzureAD authentication using OpenID and Owin middleware for Web API 2 controller within ASP.NET MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062416/how-to-bypass-azuread-authentication-using-openid-and-owin-middleware-for-web-ap) that lead me to the answer of the AllowAnonymous tag to solve my issue. Thanks all, hope this might help someone else out there.